# Can't set attribute and infinite recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use property to get the value of a class variable but the following code results in the error "can't set attribute" error and removing the line self.var3=var3 is resulting in infinite recursion. I guess I have a poor understanding of property, can someone please point out what is going wrong here.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__ (self, var1=None, var2=None):
        self.var1=var1 
        self.var2=var2

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        super(Child, self).__init__(var1=var1, var2=var2)
        self.var3=var3

    @property
    def var3(self):
        return self.var3

c1 = Child(6, 7, 8)
c2 = Child(1, 2, 3)
print c1.var1, c1.var2, c1.var3
print c2.var1, c2.var2, c2.var3
```

Comment: The infinite recursion is because `return self.var3` accesses the property (`var3`) again - use a different member variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a different name for the attribute vs. the property:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        super(Child, self).__init__(var1=var1, var2=var2)
        self._var3=var3     # added underscore

    @property
    def var3(self):
        return self._var3   # same underscore here
```

Output:

```
>>> print c1.var1, c1.var2, c1.var3
6 7 8
>>> print c2.var1, c2.var2, c2.var3
1 2 3
```